# Apache Maven: where do dependencies and libraries installed locally up?

Tags: java, maven

I'm building a Java project that has a dependency on a library. `mvn.bat clean install` produced the `target` subdirectories as expected, and the project built fine with `mvn.bat clean install` as well.

What's not expected is that when I deleted the entire directory of the library, the outer project still built fine, although the library it depends on was gone.

How does this work?

**UPDATE**: Turns out Maven makes some sort of cache in `%USERPROFILE\.m2`.

Comment: Why would you want maven not to cache ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likely thinking of your local repository where everything you install locally (and maven downloads for you from the central repository) is put for later usage.

The behavior you describe is intentional, and allows for building A once and then let B reference it whenever needed, without having to recompile A every time.  This is usually very desirable, especially in teams or with large code bases.

Note, that for changing code you should be using -SNAPSHOT artifacts. They are treated slightly differently.

Comment: Nice answer, I'll remove mine in favour of this.

Answer (score 4):

Your dependencies are *always* downloaded into .m2/repository.

If you want to have some predictability on downloaded libraries in your team, you can put in place a repository manager like Nexus : https://repository.apache.org/index.html#welcome

Instead of downloading dependencies from Maven central, your developers will download their dependencies from this repository manager.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would a repository manager make downloads more predictable?

Comment: Not always, if you change that in the `settings.xml`.

Comment: If the settings.xml is set to look for the dependencies in Nexus only and if at least one developer has downloaded one library, then the library is available in Nexus. This ensures that the library is available for all the developers even if the library is removed from Maven central or any other repository. In addition, if your create a custom artifact and place it in Nexus (for example, DB drivers...), then it ensures that every developper use the same version of this custom artifact.

Comment: @user2147970 ah, the whole idea of Maven Central is that artifacts published there never go away (as opposed to any random repositories found elsewhere on the net).  I was just wondering what you meant.  A local repository manager is very useful to avoid network dependency (is Maven Central available?) for your team.